# Lose the focus of the textboxes in gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a grid view in an updatepanel like this :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnl_lect" runat="server">
                <asp:GridView ID="gv_ques" runat="server" CssClass="formTable cr_center" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    ShowFooter="True" OnRowDataBound="gv_ques_RowDataBound">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="عناصر التقييم">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_ques" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("que_desc") %>'></asp:Label>

                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="الاجمالي"></asp:Label>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="45%" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ممتاز (4)">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txt_1" runat="server" DbValue='<%# Bind("grade_id1") %>'
                                    AutoPostBack="true" Width="60px" MinValue="0" MaxValue="999999999" OnTextChanged="txt_1_TextChanged">
                                    <NumberFormat GroupSeparator="" DecimalDigits="0" />
                                </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_1" runat="server" Value="1" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="جيد جدًا (3)">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txt_2" runat="server" DbValue='<%# Bind("grade_id2") %>'
                                    AutoPostBack="true" Width="60px" MinValue="0" MaxValue="999999999" OnTextChanged="txt_1_TextChanged">
                                    <NumberFormat GroupSeparator="" DecimalDigits="0" />
                                </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_2" runat="server" Value="2" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="جيد (2)">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txt_3" runat="server" DbValue='<%# Bind("grade_id3") %>'
                                    AutoPostBack="true" Width="60px" MinValue="0" MaxValue="999999999" OnTextChanged="txt_1_TextChanged">
                                    <NumberFormat GroupSeparator="" DecimalDigits="0" />
                                </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_3" runat="server" Value="3" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="مقبول (1)">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txt_4" runat="server" DbValue='<%# Bind("grade_id4") %>'
                                    AutoPostBack="true" Width="60px" MinValue="0" MaxValue="999999999" OnTextChanged="txt_1_TextChanged">
                                    <NumberFormat GroupSeparator="" DecimalDigits="0" />
                                </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_4" runat="server" Value="4" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_4" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ضعيف (0)">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="txt_5" runat="server" DbValue='<%# Bind("grade_id5") %>'
                                    AutoPostBack="true" Width="60px" MinValue="0" MaxValue="999999999" OnTextChanged="txt_1_TextChanged">
                                    <NumberFormat GroupSeparator="" DecimalDigits="0" />
                                </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_5" runat="server" Value="5" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_5" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

---

I lose the focus with every postback so i write the following :

```
protected void txt_1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int progSer = int.Parse(Session["prog_serial"].ToString());
            int total = 0;
            RadNumericTextBox txt = (RadNumericTextBox)sender;

            GridViewRow r = (GridViewRow)txt.NamingContainer;

            TableCell cell = null;

            Control parent = txt;
            while ((parent = parent.Parent) != null && cell == null)
                cell = parent as TableCell;
            int indexOfTextBoxCell = -1;
            if (cell != null)
                indexOfTextBoxCell = r.Cells.GetCellIndex(cell);


            foreach (GridViewRow row in gv_ques.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    total = total + int.Parse(((RadNumericTextBox)row.Cells[indexOfTextBoxCell].Controls[1]).Value.ToString());
                }
            }
            ((Label)gv_ques.FooterRow.Cells[indexOfTextBoxCell].Controls[1]).Text = total.ToString();

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "selectAndFocus", "$get('" + txt.ClientID + "').focus();$get('" + txt.ClientID + "').select();", true);//the focus
        }
```

---

Now I tab out of the textbox, the focus still doesn't quite set correctly. I have to tab once after the postback for it to work.how to set the focus to the tabbed one rather than the current textbox ?

Answer (score 5):

One solution i suggest is to use javascript [**DOM Storage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage). Keep the `id` of the focus text `input` with `local storage`:

```
$(':text').on("focus", function(){
  localStorage.setItem("focusItem", this.id);//here set in localStorage id of the textbox
  //console.log(localStorage.getItem("focusItem"));test the focus element id
});
```

And on `$(document).ready(function(){});` event you can set the focus on input textbox:

```
$('#' + localStorage.getItem("focusItem")).focus();
```

[**Here also an live example**](http://codepen.io/Chariz/pen/OPPZGP). Focus in a text and after reload the page.

Keep in mind to remove things in localStorage you have to explicitly clear them via localStorage.removeItem(itemName).

More specific info [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage). Also [**full screen live example**](http://s.codepen.io/Chariz/debug/OPPZGP?).

Comment: thanks so much `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> $(':text').on("focus", function(){ localStorage.setItem("focusItem", this.id);//here set in localStorage id of the textbox element id }); $(document).ready(function(){$('#' + localStorage.getItem("focusItem")).focus();});</script>` but it doesn't work successfully . the the `autopostback =true` of the textbox so after i click tab to move to the nextbox it goes to the first textbox in the grid instead !!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily focus on certain element using JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("txt_1").focus();
};
```

Or, if you prefer jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#txt_1").focus();
});
```

This code will focus on element with id "txt_1" after the page has completely loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the textbox you lose focus on is triggering the post back? If so,look into this, it's not a full solution but it's a start. This is more or less off the top of my head, sorry if it's not 100% correct. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383810(v=vs.100).aspx

The `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager` can get the textbox id, or an item id that int the postback. From there you can use the `document.getElementById("itemID").focus();`

```
var requestMgr = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
requestMgr.add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);

function endRequestHandler() {
  var itemID = requestMgr.args.get_postBackElement().id
  document.getElementById("itemID").focus()
}
```